# ListView Удаление item после фильтра

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть обычный ListView заполняется через simpleAdapter, фильтруется через searchView в тулбаре

```
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if (lvadapter != null) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }


        }
    });
```

удаляется так

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                
            clientsList.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Если фильтр не применялся всё прекрасно удаляется если я отфильтровал записи то удаление запускается но строки не исчезают, если я после фильтрации закрываю фильтр и снова вижу полный список, пытаюсь удалить что-то строки не исчезают. В общем во время фильтрации и после удаление перестают работать, не понимаю почему как побороть эту проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, после фильтрации в переменную, в которой содержится список, который используется адаптером, записывается новая ссылка, которая больше не совпадает со ссылкой `clientsList`. В упрощенном виде это выглядит так:

```
List clientsList = {some list of objects}; //изначальная инииализация списка
List filteredList = new ArrayList(clientsList); // примерно это происходит при фильтрации - создается новый список на основе оригинального
clientsList.remove(client); // удаление объекта из оригинального списка не удалит его из отфильтрованного.
```

Comment: Если продолжить мысль то, возможно, поможет применение заново фильтра (пусть даже с пустым значением) после удаления эл-та.

Comment: Да видимо так и происходит, но как это предусмотреть, фокус с пустым фильтром не прокатил

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу себе  сам. В общем пришлось наследоваться от SimpleAdapter и переписывать механизм фильтрации моё решение:

```
    private class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements Filterable{

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (fil == null){
            fil  = new Filtrodoble();
        }
        return fil;
    }

    class Filtrodoble extends Filter{

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> tmpItems;

        public Filtrodoble() {
            super();
            tmpItems = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpItems.addAll(clientsList);
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // convert search string to lower case - the filtering is not case sensitive
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            // define the result object
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            // define a place to hole the items that pass filtering
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> filteredItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();


            // loop through the original list and any items that pass filtering are added to the "filtered" list
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {

                for(int i = 0; i < tmpItems.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> tmp = tmpItems.get(i);
                    String candidate = tmp.get(LoadAllShopers.TAG_NAME).toString().toLowerCase();


                    if(candidate.contains(constraint) ) {
                        filteredItems.add(tmp);
                    }
                }
                // set the result to the "filtered" list.
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                // if nothing to filter on -  then the result is the complete input set
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    filteredItems.clear();
                    filteredItems.addAll( tmpItems);
                    result.values = filteredItems;
                    result.count = filteredItems.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            clientsList.clear();
            clientsList.addAll((Collection<? extends HashMap<String, Object>>) results.values);
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }

}
```